# User with multiple accounts

Tags: discussion

What's the community's take on users with multiple accounts?

The case I have in mind concerns a user ([ID1](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/15030/studying1234)/[ID2](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/14785/none009)/[ID3](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/6134/b11b)) who frequently asks homework-type questions (some with shown effort, others without). The user also frequently cross-posts on other SE platforms and deletes his/her own questions that either got excessive downvotes or received no answers. Also, one of his/her accounts on MSE is under temporary suspension "for voting irregularities".

As far as I can tell, the multiple accounts are created not to game the SE reputation system, but to ask questions. The user appears to be a genuine learner, has been very polite and caused no noticeable disruption to the community. However, the type and number of questions that this user asks do raise suspicion that he/she may have been trying to outsource a lot homework question here.

---

**Update on May 9.**

Two new IDs are detected ([ID4](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/18244/stefanos-makridis)/[ID5](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/18231/gme7)). These IDs also posted quite a few low-effort / low-quality questions in the past 24 hours:

- [Homothetic preference and the price elasticity of demand](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/21910/42)
- [Show that First order conditions are necessary and sufficient for utility maximization.](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/21906/42)
- [Question about budget constraint and utility maximization](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/21908/42)
- [Inferior and normal good and the change in price of those goods](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/21909/42)
- [optimization problem with Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/21902/42)

Comment: This user's "can you please see my related question" [answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/22015/1601) to an old question just got an upvote from 'someone'.

Comment: @denesp: I flagged it for moderator attention. The user also posted several such "please see my other question" comments under answers to his previous questions.

Comment: It's ridiculous the way he's [editing his own questions with a different account](https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/21945/revisions). It's almost as if he didn't bother to log out of his other account, but still wanted to make an edit.

Comment: Now he has at least one [new account](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/18566/b11b) with a "." at the end.

Comment: @denesp: From the pattern of his questions (a bunch of micro followed by a bunch of macro, and now micro again), it looks like he's preping/taking some sort of qualifying/comprehensive exams. It doesn't help that most of his questions receive answers, which in turn encourages more of such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The network consensus seems to be that multiple accounts are okay, provided they are not being used to game the system (e.g.,  by voting for your own posts). See, e.g., [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Thanks for flagging the particular case: the mods have tools to check for sock-puppet voting and indeed it seems to be going on here.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Also see my update in the question.